# python regular expression repeated characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to create a regular expression in python that matches all DNA sequences starting with `T` followed by `18` characters (any characters) and then terminated by either `AA`, `TT`, `CC` or `GG`. I can manage the first part but I can't seem to find a way to write the end (the double characters) without duplicating the regex 4 times.
Here's what I have for a sequence ending in `TT`:

```
import re
seq='ATGTGTGGACACAAGTGACAGTTTACGATGAGGTTACAGCCCGCA'
match=re.findall('T.{18}TT',seq)
print match
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [a good tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

There is a concept called alternation. It matches any one of the given options:

```
r'T.{18}(?:TT|AA|CC|GG)'
```

Note that you should use raw strings to encode regexes in Python, otherwise you will get problems with escaping characters later.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately the code given works but with the re.search() method since I am using the re.findall() method I found that I should use 'T.{18}(?:TT|AA|CC|GG)' instead because findall() doesn't deal with regexp groups the same way search() does.

Comment: @AlexeiBassinski it is generally a good idea to add the `?:` if you don't specifically need to capture the subgroup. I just left it out to keep the solution as basic as possible.